# Computer hanged at loading screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 16/Windows 10 on my computer. Overnight, it got stuck on the motherboard brand screen at startup (the loading screen from which the bios can be accessed).

I tried to boot with Ubuntu first, then Windows first, then with a flash Windows UDB, then with Ubuntu's recovery mode and nothing worked.

Do you have any suggestion ?

EDIT: Here some informations asked in the comments

1) "Have there been any firmware updates to the machine recently?" - I don't know at all

2) "Have there been any edits to the BIOS?" - Not before the bug. I tried a lot of things in the BIOS in order boot the computer but nothing worked. I restored default parameters.

3) "when you unplug any and all USB devices does the machine still experience problems?" - Yes, I tried to unplug everything but it didn't change anthing

4) "What make/model is the motherboard?" B350 PC MATE(MS-7AB4)

SECOND EDIT: I tried to change the battery on the motherboard, it doesn't change anything. The clock is still working when I check it on the BIOS.

FINAL EDIT: a SATA port on the power side was dysfunctional. By changing the SSD location, it fixed everything. Thank you for your help

Comment: Would you be able to provide the following: 1) Have there been any firmware updates to the machine recently? 2) Have there been any edits to the BIOS? 3) when you unplug any and all USB devices does the machine still experience problems? 4) What make/model is the motherboard? Thank you!

Comment: Edited my question to give you some infos

Comment: Can you remove everything internally apart from the power supply? Leave the CPU fan plugged in. Use the built in video adapter (VGA) for your screen if you used a video card. What messages do you get?

Comment: Removed everything, including the HDD and the SDD (where OS are installed). Nothing appears on the screen

Comment: Added components one by one (first SDD then HDD, then the RAM...)
Nothing appears on the screen, it looks like the built in HDMI/DVI of the motherboard are not working. I don't have any VGA cable

Comment: I checked in the BIOS and I can't activate the internal graphics of the motherboard